# Kotlin common base type of types representing whole numbers?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, typing

Does Kotlin offer a way to describe a 'whole number' such as `Int`, `Long` or `BigInteger` but **not** `Double`?

In Kotlin, as in Java, there is `Number` as the supertype of all numerical types including the floating-point numbers. Java does not let you exclude the floating-points, as the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Integer.html) about the numerical types state that they directly subclass the abstract class `Number` and implement no Interfaces (except Comparable and Serializable).

In the Kotlin-documentation, I could not find any such whole-number-type, but I did not find any definitive List of numerical types or a statement that says such a whole-number-type was purposefully not included.

Comment: I asked this question while trying to find the "whole-number-interface" (I assumed it would exist) and came across a definitive answer myself (using Kotlins source-code). While my question is resolved I would prefer an answer that points me to official documentation or a note by the developers of Kotlin explaining how the number-hierarchy is designed, especially with respect to Java-compatibility.

Comment: I know that "Why"-questions are off-topic, so lets phrase it like this: What was my misunderstanding about subtyping on the JVM when I assumed that such a type should exist?

Comment: What would be the use of such a type? I've never even found a use for Number in 13 years of Java programming. As for the downvote, maybe someone thought it was unclear to ask such a question without explaining why you would expect such a feature or what it could possibly be used for. But I think there are a lot of nonsensical downvotes on this site so it could just be that.

Comment: I am writing a module that works internally with BigInteger but takes any input without forcing the `toBigInteger`-boilerplate on the user and without having to overload all my methods. But I felt that context is unnecessary to the question. I expected the feature to exist because: A) kotlin does a lot to avoid boilerplate B) this is a feature which can only be provided by language designers C) It could be added in a backwards-compatible way (just add an interface whose methods are already there)

Comment: The close-vote says "needs detail or clarity". To me the question is so clear that I could answer it with "No" and definitive proof of that "No". What is missing? I will try to improve the post if someone tells me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no such type.**

Looking into the source-code of Kotlin we can see that the type-hierarchy of numbers is exactly the same as in Java: All number-types directly subclass `Number` and implement no interface that would describe them further.

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt